# How to create a pathway knockout using the JavaScript library ESCHER?

Tags: pathway

I want to create my own pathway with a custom knockout function using [ESCHER](https://escher.github.io/). Consider the pathway knockout [link](https://escher.github.io/escher-demo/knockout/).

As you can see by clicking the reaction the color changes and the text with the html/css id `knockout-status` adds the reactions that was clicked and the growth rate.

I am trying to work out how the `knockout.js`  handles the clicks and changes the colors. so far I would say that this block - as commented -  handles the clicks

```javascript
// initialize event listeners
var sel = builder.selection;
sel.selectAll('.reaction,.reaction-label')
    .style('cursor', function(d) {
        if (knockable(d.bigg_id)) return 'pointer';
        else return null;
    })
    .on('click', function(d) {
        if (knockable(d.bigg_id)) {
            if (!(d.bigg_id in knockouts))
                knockouts[d.bigg_id] = true;
            model = knock_out_reaction(model, d.bigg_id);
            solve_and_display(model, knockouts);
        }
    });
// grey for reactions that cannot be knocked out
sel.selectAll('.reaction-label')
    .style('fill', function(d) {
        if (!knockable(d.bigg_id)) return '#888';
        else return null;
    });
```

and the `'.reaction,.reaction-label'` finds all css class with the reactions. What I am missing is how to create my own maps with my own click listener? I checked the [documentation](https://escher.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) but it handles more the creation of the maps, but I am also want to build the js knockout functionality. Could someone maybe show on a small example with 4-5 reactions how I could create my own maps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to relate to a specific issue, and is asking too much out of answers. Please demonstrate what you've already tried, and highlight the points where it is not working as you expect.